# Ruby << for String

Tags: ruby

Can someone tell me the name of

```
<<-MAP 
STRING HERE
MAP
```

operator `(<<-)` in ruby? I tried search for 'double less than' but it didn't turn up anything. I want to learn more about it but don't even know what it's called!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thats called the here doc syntax .Generally used to enter multiline strings. You can read about it here http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html

and also here [The <<- operator on Ruby, where is it documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644132/the-operator-on-ruby-where-is-it-documented)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an operator, it's a *here document* (aka *heredoc*) `String` literal. It works more or less like heredocs in other languages.

It is specified in section 8.7.6.3.6 of the ISO Ruby Language Specification.