# sed script not executing in a Vagrantfile

Tags: sed, vagrant

I can't for the life of me get sed working with vagrant provisioning. I want to make a inline change to /etc/hosts.

I've verified that the sed command works when run in the shell.

Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
# vi: set ft=ruby :

########### Global Config ###########
machines = ["admin2"]
num_hdd_per_osd = 3
vagrant_box = %q{bento/ubuntu-18.04}
#####################################


machines.each do |machine| 
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
        config.vm.define machine do |node| #name vagrant uses to reference this VM
            node.vm.box = vagrant_box
            node.vm.hostname = machine
            node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.0.#{ machines.index(machine) + 10}"

            node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
                # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
                vb.gui = false
                vb.name = machine # name virtualbox uses to refer to this vm
                # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
                vb.memory = "1048"
                # Core Count
                vb.cpus = "2"
            end

            if node.vm.hostname.include? "admin"
                node.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
                    sed -i.bak -e 's,\\(127\\.0\\.0\\.1[[:space:]]*localhost\\),\\1aa,' /etc/hosts
                SHELL
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I should see /etc/hosts changed to `127.0.0.1       localhostaa` but it is unchanged.

What is wrong?

**EDIT:** I updated the code with the suggestion from Alex below. It now uses inline: <<-SHELL and escaped ALL escapes (so double escape). It Works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem there is your Vagrantfile is Ruby code, and your sed script is inside a Ruby here string.

If you try this simplified Ruby script:

```ruby
# test.rb
puts <<-SHELL
sudo sed -i.bak -e 's,\(127\.0\.0\.1[[:space:]]*localhost\),\1aa,' /etc/host
SHELL
```

You may see the problem:

```
▶ ruby test.rb  
sudo sed -i.bak -e 's,(127.0.0.1[[:space:]]*localhost),aa,' /etc/host
```

That is, the `\1` and other `\` have been interpreted by Ruby prior to interpolation in the here string.

The best option for you is to use the `<<'SHELL'` notation, similar to what you would do in Bash:

```ruby
node.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-'SHELL'
  sed -i.bak -e 's,\(127\.0\.0\.1[[:space:]]*localhost\),\1aa,' /etc/hosts
SHELL
```

The other option would be to escape the backslash in `\1`. Also, note that, as far as I can tell, the call to `sudo` is not required there either.

If, however, you need to interpolate a string in this script, you could do something like this:

```ruby
# test.rb
mystring = 'aa'
$script = "sed -i.bak -e '" +
  's,\(127\.0\.0\.1[[:space:]]*localhost\),\1' + "#{mystring},' /etc/hosts"
```

And then in your provisioner:

```ruby
node.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1644223/3787051) related answer.

Comment: I don't see what is different about what I posted and your solution other than the ticks around SHELL and hyphen. When I copy your code verbatim, it get 

```
There is a syntax error in the following Vagrantfile. The syntax error
message is reproduced below for convenience:

C:/Users/<user>/Vagrantfile:36: can't find string "SHELL" anywhere before EOF
C:/Users/<user>/Vagrantfile:29: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
ion "shell", inline: <<'SHELL'
```

Comment: @TarekZ, actually I have updated to show a better Ruby syntax to use, i.e. `<<-'SHELL' ... SHELL`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: worked! thank you. Can you briefly tell me what the difference between <<-SHELL and <<-'SHELL' is ? That's the only difference I see between our code. (fyi also when I added a backslash to the \n in my original code if failed even though in the test.rb w puts, it looked right)

Comment: @TarekZ, it is explained in detail in the question I linked at the bottom of the answer, but adding those single quotes around SHELL causes Ruby to not perform any interpolations in the string. There is also a similar grammar in Bash, Perl and other languages.

Comment: I read the linked doc again, maybe quotes (not ticks) will allow #{variable} to be interpolated? I can try

Comment: @TarekZ , yes, if you do need to interpolate inside the here string then you should just escape all the backslashes and use the original <<-SHELL notation.

Comment: @TarekZ, as I said, you would escape _all_ the backslashes. However, now that you've said you do want to interpolate in this string, there are better ways. One minute.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I missed the *all* comment. Then I realized it myself and caught it as you were answering :). I would like a better method because escaping multiple times gets messy. Thank you!!!!

Comment: My update might suggest how you can clean it up, @TarekZ.